# How can i export to csv or xls using PHP , in different worksheets

Tags: php

How can i export data in different work sheets.

If data is more than 25000 , i want to write next 25000 in next worksheet,

in xls data can be in different tabs..

How can i make that structure using PHP export to csv or xls.

Will it help to reduce load , if i write in different sheets.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the PEAR class [Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer) can create multiple worksheets.

I don't think adding worksheets will reduce load, because the filesize will still be the same.  I'd suggest you use multiple files instead, if load/filesize is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

[PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) is another library, similar to the PEAR Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer class, that can write to multiple worksheets; but it won't necessarily reduce load. If you have more than 25,000 rows (for example, in an array) then this will be using a lot of PHP's memory

Comment: you have any suggesion to reduce the load. when working with huge data

Comment: If you're reading data from a db, don't build an array... just process each record as you retrieve it and then discard it. Or build a CSV file using fputcsv, irrespective of the number of rows... creating an Excel workbook will take more PHP resource (Excel95/Excel2003 can read CSV files up to 65536 rows, Excel2007+ can read up to a million rows)